# android. Получение координат через сеть

Tags: android

Добрый день.
Пытаюсь определить местоположение через Network Provider, но ничего не выходит. С GPS все работает. ниже код:

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener
{
    private static final String TAG="myLog";

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    LocationManager lm =
            (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        Log.d(TAG, "Широта="+location.getLatitude());
        Log.d(TAG, "Долгота="+location.getLongitude());
    }
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider)
{
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider)
{
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras)
{
}
```

}

В логах ничего не высвечивается. В манифесте все объявил. В чем может быть проблема? Тестирую на телефоне xiaomi, может они чего там намудрили?

Comment: В манифесте прописали ?
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

Comment: Да, все прописано.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вот части рабочего примера

```
manifest
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

onCreate(...){
//Подключаем GPS
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        startGPS();

}

private void startGPS() {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // TODO: Consider calling
            //    ActivityCompat#requestPermissions
            // here to request the missing permissions, and then overriding
            //   public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
            //                                          int[] grantResults)
            // to handle the case where the user grants the permission. See the documentation
            // for ActivityCompat#requestPermissions for more details.
            //return;
        }
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 1000 * 10, 10, locationListener);
        progressBarGPS.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        Log.i(Const.TAG, "onClick: ");
    }

    private LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.i(Const.TAG, "onLocationChanged: " + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude());
            //Отобразим координаты
            new ParseTask("" + location.getLatitude() + "," + location.getLongitude()).execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            //checkEnabled();
            //Log.i(TAG, "onProviderDisabled: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            //checkEnabled();
            //showLocation(locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider));
            //Log.i(TAG, "onProviderEnabled: ");
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
            //if (provider.equals(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            //    tvStatusGPS.setText("Status: " + String.valueOf(status));
            //} else if (provider.equals(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER)) {
            //    tvStatusNet.setText("Status: " + String.valueOf(status));
            //}
            //Log.i(TAG, "onStatusChanged: ");
        }
    };
```

Comment: не знаю что произошло но мой код заработал. Видимо все же дело было с телефоном, т.к. прилетело обновление и все стало работать. Спасибо за помощь